# lotus domino PUT and DELETE methods are not working

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

Lotus domino PUT and DELETE methods are not working from the REST api.I am using DELETE URL: http:///mail/user.nsf/api/calendar/events/14749AC71ED8A2CB65257EA5001F4B79-Lotus_Auto_Generated

Comment: This question could be improved.  The phrase "not working" is ambiguous.  What HTTP status code is returned?  Also, what is in the body of the response?  JSON, HTML or nothing?  Please describe exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the PUT and DELETE methods on your internet site document as they default are not enabled

Comment: Thanks.But i don't have internet site document.

Comment: You should use internet site documents. See this IBM tech note on how to enable the methods: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21201202

Answer (score 0):

If you continue having trouble with PUT and DELETE, you could try using POST with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header.  The header is described in [this topic](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Specifying_request_headers_das901&content=apicontent) on the IBM app dev wiki.